# Git for Windows Commits

Tags: github, git-commit, github-for-windows

I've been tasked to make a presentation about a topic, but every slide should be added into a repository as a commit using Git for Windows. My question is if I just add the file each time manually to the repository, will it look different then if i did it by Git for Windows? Thank you

Tried adding the file manually but im a noob so i dont know if theres a difference

Comment: There's always commit when creating new files, deleting or changing them even if it happened via some UI or command line.

Comment: Check https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial